# Calling "doveadm acl" remotely throws "Unknown command 'acl', but plugin acl exists"

Tags: dovecot

I'm trying to configure Dovecot's ACLs remotely (using doveadm -S), like this:

`doveadm -o doveadm_password=secret acl add -u shared@domain.com -S mailsrv:24242 inbox user=user@domain.com lookup read write-seen`

But I'm getting this error:

`Fatal: Unknown command 'acl', but plugin acl exists. Try to set mail_plugins=acl`

If I try to run the same command directly on the server itself, it works:

`doveadm acl add -u shared@domain.com inbox user=user@domain.com lookup read write-seen`

Moreover, if I try another command **remotely**, such as "sieve list", it works too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on the server, it's on the client you run doveadm from. To fix it check the `mail_plugins` setting inside /etc/dovecot **on the client**.